# What is the problem if the temperature of the oil and heads of cylinders is too high?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, piston-engine

What is the problem if the temperature of the  oil and heads of cylinders is too high? What's the fault in piston engines?

Comment: Had anyone mention kaboommm!!!!?!

Comment: Engines contain explosions. Metal gets weak when too hot. End result?

Comment: Your edit changed the meaning of your question, invalidating the (good) answers you received. As originally stated, the question seemed to ask about the bad ***effects*** of high temperatures; now it asks about ***causes***.  Might be best to revert your edit & ask a new question about causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piston engines are designed to run within specific temperature ranges. Going above this range might effect the lubrication [hot oil may not provide the right amount of protection to moving parts, If hot enough it could melt seals, or even catch fire.]
the other danger is as metal changes temperature its structural property's change. If a metal gets too hot it becomes softer and may become less resistance to forces. also there is the issue of shock cooling, if a hot engine gets cooled to quickly, it may unevenly cool, and due to the difference in heat expansion could crack or fail.